# How to combine four queries in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have draws on my site, in order to take part in the draw, you need to do a certain action per day. And there is a code that checks it all:

```
    $date = Carbon::today();
    $sta = \DB::table('ets')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('created_at', '>=', $date)->get();
    $sta = \DB::table('ets_1x1')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('created_at', '>=', $date)->get();
    $sta = \DB::table('ets_low')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('created_at', '>=',$date)->get();
    $sta = \DB::table('ets_duel')->where('user_id', $this->user->id)->where('created_at', '>=', $date)->get();

if ($sta == NULL) {
                return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Error']);
            }
```

This code checks if there is a user record in 4 possible tables. I made an entry in the table `ets_1x1`, but still I can’t take part, because the error seemed to not find me in the database. I removed all the tables and left only `ets_1x1` and I was accepted into the drawing.

As I understand it, the value is taken from the last request. How can I combine a query into 1 and do a check on these 4 tables?

**UPD:**

I also tried to give new names to the variables and display the response code differently, now participation in the drawing is accepted from all people, even from those who have not fulfilled the conditions, now it looks:

```
    if(!empty($sta_1) || !empty($sta_2) || !empty($sta_3) || !empty($sta_4)) {
        return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Error']);
    }
```

Where my mistake?

Comment: you are assigning value to same variable is not merging it overriding  use join all table

Comment: you mean use first vartation, but after `->get` use `->join`?

Comment: all table have user_id so only in where 1st table will have where condtion and rest will have join on  ets.user_id = ets_1x1.user_id and so one

Comment: I'm still not clear what do u need? do u need the datas from these four tables?

Comment: it seems like you have one to many relation with other 4 table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is not going to work because:

1. The first piece of code will evaluate only the last request (and in consecuence, only if there is any existent user on the last table only).
2. The second piece of code is not being evaluated correctly, you are running empty function on a Laravel collection.

Why don't you try this? I think it should work:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$userExists = false;
$tables = ['ets', 'ets_1x1', 'ets_low', 'ets_duel'];

foreach ($tables as $tableName) {
    $result = \DB::table($tableName)
        ->where('user_id', $this->user->id)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', $date)
        ->get()
    ;
    if ($result->isNotEmpty()) {
        $userExists = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!$userExists) {
    return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'Error']);
}
```